# BusyBox file upload [POST] with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, busybox

I have a device running a restrictive version of busybox that has an hdmi output. I need to upload an image, to use as the splash screen when the device boots up. The manufacturer provides a tftp method of doing this, but it doesn't really work, and they are less than enthusiastic about helping.

### What I have

[image: busybox details]

I have telnet access to the device. There is no text editor so I am creating the script like this:

> echo "#!/bin/bash
>
> (
>
> while read -d '' line ; do
>
> printf '%s\n' \"\$line\"
>
> done
>
> ) > /www/images/test.gif
>
> echo 'Status: 204 No Content'
>
> echo ;;
>
> esac" > file.cgi

The script is a modified version of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79626

The device already has an http server running, and I am able to POST a file to the script successfully. Text files (txt,html) upload correctly and I am able to view them through the devices web interface.

However, the same cannot be said for images. The upload completes, and I am able to view the contents of the file (cat `image` produces *PNG [binary output] *). The file size is correct or a near approximation of what is expected. Bringing the file up in the web browser produces a broken image with Chrome telling me that `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png: "http://169.254.3.163/test.png".`

I am a regular linux user but this type of interact is my weak spot, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have `ftpget` which is intended for file transfers

Comment: While I could do that, it would require the use of an ftp server, and I was hoping to avoid the extra dependency. I am using an external control program I've written to control the device, and  I would rather not have to force the application to act as an ftp server unless there is no other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to read from stdin, and assuming you can write to `/www/images`, this is the cgi script:

```
#! /bin/sh

cat - > /www/images/test.gif
echo "

OK"
```

Comment: Wow. I was way over complicating things. This worked beautifully.